# How to not execute everything in AndroidView update block

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So let's say I have screen like this:

```
@Composable
fun CustomMapView(
    isActive: Boolean,
    currentlyDisplayedText: String, 
) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
             MapView(it)
        },
        update = { mapView ->
            mapView.addLayer(
                isActive = isActive,
                title = currentlyDisplayedText,
            )
            mapView.reorderLayers()
        },
    )
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that whenever `isActive` or `currentlyDisplayedText` changes the whole update block is executed. The is not optimal, since I only need to call             `mapView.reorderLayers()`, whenever `currentlyDisplayedText` changes. But currently the method is called even if just `isActive` changes. Is there any option to check what exactly has changed in update block or something else that could solve this problem?

I tried searching Compose documentation, but all I can find is that if state that you read in the update changes it is going to execute the whole block again.

I tried using LaunchedEffect or remember, but can't since we are not in composable scope.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a built-in way, you need to check for yourself if `currentlyDisplayedText` changed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried. I added a new flag into state called textChanged, which I set to true and then I can know when to call reorder layer, but I need to reset it afterwards. It works, but it's just not really nice fix.

Answer (score 0):

The update block is called by design in this case. If you remove the usage of the parameter isActive in the update block, then update is called only if currentlyDisplayedText changes.

If your problem is, that isActive does change to frequently, you have to ensure outside the call of the AndroidView Component, that you transform it to a value with less updates.